# Escaping spaces in path names

Tags: macos, bash, sed

I am trying to escape spaces in a path name `/Volumes/NO NAME`. I need to access files present within this directory via a `bash` script. I have used `sed` and `printf` commands and neither seems to have worked. The code I have so far:

```
while read line
do
  if [[ -d ${line} ]]; then
    echo "${line} is a directory. Skipping this.";
  elif [[ -f ${line} ]]; then
    spacedOutLine=`echo ${line} | sed -e 's/ /\\ /g'`;
    #spacedOutLine=$(printf %q "$line");
    echo "line = ${line} and spacedOutLine = ${spacedOutLine}";
  else
    echo "Some other type of file. Unrecognized.";
  fi
done < ${2}
```

Neither of this seems to have worked. For an input like: `/Volumes/NO NAME/hello.txt`, the output is:

```
/Volumes/NO: No such file or directory
NAME/hello.txt: No such file or directory
```

I am on a Mac and using `bash` via the terminal. I have also gone through a lot of other posts on SO about this which have not helped me.

Comment: Don't try to manually escape spaces in the value of a variable. Just quote the variable whenever it is expanded, and the spaces will be preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes while calling the `${line}` variable.

```
"${line}"
```